# My Table doesn't show any item , error in console.log(e.responseText)

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

This is my code of the table, I dont know where is the error guys, apparently the error is on the line 124 of the javascript:

```
console.log(e.responseText)
```

But the console of the browser don't show errors, sorry for my bad english.

*JAVASCRIPT TABLE FUNCTION*

```
function ListadoArticulos(){
var tabla = $('#tblArticulos').dataTable(
    {   "aProcessing": true,
        "aServerSide": true,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ],
        "aoColumns":[
                {   "mDataProp": "id"},
                {   "mDataProp": "1"},
                {   "mDataProp": "2"},
                {   "mDataProp": "3"},
                {   "mDataProp": "4"},
                {   "mDataProp": "5"},
                {   "mDataProp": "6"},
                {   "mDataProp": "7"},
                {   "mDataProp": "8"},
                {   "mDataProp": "9"},   
                {   "mDataProp": "10"},  
                {   "mDataProp": "11"},   
                {   "mDataProp": "12"},   
                {   "mDataProp": "13"},   
                {   "mDataProp": "14"},   
                {   "mDataProp": "15"},   
                {   "mDataProp": "16"},   
                {   "mDataProp": "17"},  
                {   "mDataProp": "18"},   
                {   "mDataProp": "19"},  
                {  "mDataProp": "20"}
                ],"ajax":
            {
                url: './ajax/ArticuloAjax.php?op=list',
                type : "get",
                dataType : "json",

                error: function(e){
                    console.log(e.responseText);
                }
            },
        "bDestroy": true

    }).DataTable();

};
```

*PHP*

```
public function Listar(){
        global $conexion;

  $sql ="SELECT * FROM articulo";

        $query = $conexion->query($sql);
        return $query;
    }
```

*AJAX*

```
case "list":
        $query_Tipo = $objArticulo->Listar();
        $data = Array();
        $i = 1;
        while ($reg = $query_Tipo->fetch_object()) {

            $data[] = array("id"=>$i,
                "1"=>$reg->idarticulo,
                "2"=>$reg->cantidad,
                "3"=>$reg->titulo,
                "4"=>$reg->nombre,
                "5"=>$reg->apellido,
      "6"=>$reg->isbn,
                "7"=>$reg->Editorial,
              "8"=>$reg->Pais,///agregado para ver el error
        "9"=>$reg->Categoria,///agregado para ver el error
                "10"=>$reg->Costo,///agregado para ver el error
                "11"=>$reg->Precio,///agregado para ver el error
                "12"=>$reg->Pdescuento,///agregado para ver el error
                "13"=>$reg->Total,///agregado para ver el error
                "14"=>$reg->Ubicacion,///agregado para ver el error
                "15"=>'<img width=100px height=100px src="./'.$reg->imagen.'" />',///agregado para ver el error
                "16"=>$reg->Cbarra,///agregado para ver el error
                "17"=>$reg->date,///agregado para ver el error
                "18"=>$reg->Distribuidor,
              '<button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar" onclick="cargarDataArticulo('.$reg->idarticulo.',\''.$reg->cantidad.'\',\''.$reg->nombre.'\',\''.$reg->apellido.'\',\''.$reg->Editorial.'\',\''.$reg->isbn.'\',\''.$reg->imagen.'\')"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </button>&nbsp;'.
                '<button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar" onclick="eliminarArticulo('.$reg->idarticulo.')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </button>');
            $i++;
        }
        $results = array(
        "sEcho" => 1,
        "iTotalRecords" => count($data),
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($data),
        "aaData"=>$data);
        echo json_encode($results);

        break;
```

*HTML*

```
<table id="tblArticulos" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Idarticulo</th>
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>Titulo</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Apellido</th>
                        <th>ISBN</th>
                        <th>Editorial</th>
                        <th>Pais</th>
                        <th>Categoria</th>
                        <th>Costo</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Descuento</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Ubicacion</th>
                        <th>Imagen</th>
                        <th>Cbarra</th>
                        <th>Año</th>
                        <th>Ingresado</th>
                        <th>Distribuidor</th>
                        <th>Opciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="articulo">

              </tbody>
            </table>
```

I dont know what is the error, I have trying days to view my data in the table but don't show anything.
Some images of the table and the page:
[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhJLL.jpg)

ERROR IN THE CONSOLE:

```
Articulo.js:124 Arguments(3)0: {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}1: "parsererror"2: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at n.parseJSON (http://localhost/solventas2/public/js/jquery.min.js:4:5497)
at ub (http://localhost/solventas2/public/js/jquery.min.js:4:7521)
at x (http://localhost/solventas2/public/js/jquery.min.js:4:10935)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://localhost/solventas2/public/js/jquery.min.js:4:14765)callee: ƒ (e)length: 3Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ values()__proto__: Object
```

Comment: I doubt `e` has `responseText` property - that error callback probably has 3 arguments, console log them instead to see the error - try `console.log(arguments)` instead

Comment: I edited the post and added the console log, please read it

Comment: so, the error you're getting is the server is sending badly formatted JSON - fix the server side code